# HTML and MySQL problems using latin characters

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to create my first web page using Yii, PHP and MySQL. I have some problems using latin characters. When I write these characters I can't show them correctly, for example:

```
ID: 1   
Username: JosÃ© MiguelEDITADO
Password: contraseÃ±aJosemi
```

Besides, I have the same problem when I try to store this characters in the DB. I mean, when I complete a form field and click on submit, if one of theses fields have latin characters, the DB only store the text of the field up to the latin character. For example:

If write "María" in the form field the DB store "Mar" inthe corresponding register.

I know that I have a problem with the charset but I don't know why. In the db array of my main.php I have:

```
    'db'=>array(
                     ...
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Besides in the registers of my DB I use "varchar(100) utf8_general_ci". In the document main.php I also have:

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'Prueba',
'language'=>'es',
'sourceLanguage'=>'en',
'charset'=>'utf-8',
```

I am using notepad++ to edit and to create the php documents, and the codification of these documents is UTF-8 sin BOM.

Please, I need your help, I don't know that is my error. Somebody could help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's your file meta charset? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Hello Bora, I use:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset-<?php echo Yii::app()->charset;?>" /> so I think that I use utf-8

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode)?

Comment: Yes Michael, thanks, and I THINK that I am doing everything well, but I don't know why I can't swhow correctly latin characters....